# Fastest way of avoiding a for loop in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

I have a function which takes a scalar as an argument. I want to map a numpy array as argument of this function.

```
def myfn(scalar):
    return transformed_scalar
```

I know about np.vectorize, which I have already used to vectorize it

```
vmyfunc = np.vectorize(myfn)
mapped_array = vmyfunc([x1,x2,...,xn])
```

Reading the documentation I realized it's just a for loop, see quote below:

> Notes
>
> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
>   performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop

I'm looking for another way that improves to implement this vectorization of the function that improves the performance of this method.
Maybe something using pandas?

**UPDATE**

The function that takes the scalar looks like the following:

```
def Loss_func(x, y, W):
  delta = 1.0
  scores = W.dot(np.transpose(x))
  margins = np.maximum(0, scores - scores[y] + delta)
  margins[y] = 0
  loss_i = np.sum(margins)
  return loss_i
```

Where y a scalar, X and W 2-D np arrays.

Comment: It would help if you explained what your function is actually trying to do by posting inputs, code and desired output

Comment: Generally, you'd write your function in such a way that it handles arrays natively. How this works would depend on what your function is. There's a good chance it handles arrays already, if the operations involved are simple.

Comment: Are you trying to make `Loss_func` work with multiple values of `y`?  Or larger dimensioned `X` and `W`?  Give us a concrete example with iteration.  That makes it easier to test alternatives.  We like to copy-n-paste working code.

Comment: Take `W.dot(np.transpose(x))` out of the loop?

Comment: what's the shape of scores?